# Django NoReverMatch at /

Tags: python, django, url, web, django-urls

I read the book 'Django By Example' and run the examples in chaper7.
But the results call "NoReverMatch at /"

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(5, u'ironman')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[\\d+])/(?P<slug>[-\\w+])/$']
```

This is the models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])



class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

This is the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w+])/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

This is the views.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {'category': category,   'categories': categories, 'products': products})



def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                            id=id,
                            slug=slug,
                            available=True)

    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

And this is the 'list.html' template where the error occurs.

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <ul>
            <li {% if not category %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
                <a href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">All</a>
            </li>
            {% for c in categories %}
                <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
                    <a href="c.get_absolute_url">{{ c.name }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="product-list">
        <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %} </h1>
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="item">
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
            </a>
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a><br>
           ${{ product.price }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error occurs at

```
<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
```

-- line.
Why this error occurs??

Comment: The second and third line in models.py is not indented. If it is the same in your code then fix it and run your code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to change your url pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w+])/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail')
```

perhaps to:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail')
```

`'+'` does not function as a special character inside square brackets, so `[-\w+]` will only match a single character (alphanumeric or `'-'`), but you are passing multi-character strings like `'ironman'`. `[-\w]+` will match one or more characters.

Comment: Ahhhh.... Why I couldn't see that?.......Than you very much!!! You saved my life !!!

Comment: @DaWoonJung no problem. It is tricky, and easy to mix up even if you know that `'+'` doesn't work inside `[]`